# Boto3:TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to get the value of *private IP address* of an instance which gets created from a **cloudformation stack**. I'm able to see full details about the instance from response output. However when I'm trying to
pick up the particular value, it fails with the error `'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'`

```
def update_hosts(Stack_Name):
    client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    stack_resources = client.list_stack_resources(StackName=Stack_Name)
    for resource in stack_resources['StackResourceSummaries']:
        if resource['ResourceType'] == 'AWS::EC2::Instance' and resource['ResourceStatus'] == 'CREATE_COMPLETE':
            instance = (resource['PhysicalResourceId'])
            response=ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance])
            print(response['Reservations']['Instances']['ImageId'])
```

Output of response:
`{'Reservations': [{'Groups': [], 'Instances': [{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'xxx', 'InstanceId': 'i-xxx', 'InstanceType': 'xxx',..................}}`

Error Output:-`'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'`

I'm interested in picking up a particular value say **ImageId/InstanceId** in the output.
Can someone suggest how this can be achieved.

Comment: please post the full traceback.  it's difficult to judge where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the docs [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) `Reservations` and `Instances` **are lists**.

Thus, you can do the following:

```
for reservation in response['Reservations']:
   for instance in reservation['Instances']:
     print(instance['ImageId'])
```

instead of

```
print(response['Reservations']['Instances']['ImageId'])
```